# Python: Create a plot that show the departments expenses over time in each department:

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im new to python but im having an issue with getting the right information into a graph.

There is several different departments that all has different invoices for payments during an entire year. I want to be able to group them so I can see the amount the invoices adds up to each months in each department in a box graph.

Im currently able to get the frequency of how many times the department got an invoice in each month over a year, but I want the amount instead of frequency

This is my code so far

```
df['Udstedelsesdato'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Udstedelsesdato'])
df = df[(df['Udstedelsesdato'].dt.year == 2019)]
df = df[df.OrganisationNiveau3 != 'Direktionen , Fælles område'] 
df = df[df.OrganisationNiveau3 != 'Kommunaldirektørens Stabe']
df = df[df.OrganisationNiveau3 != 'Kultur og Erhverv']
df = df[df.OrganisationNiveau3 != 'Økonomi']

plot_df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Udstedelsesdato',freq='M'), 'OrganisationNiveau3'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .pivot(index='Udstedelsesdato', columns='OrganisationNiveau3', values='count')
)
# Plot Bar
ax = plot_df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylabel='Frequency', xlabel =' Months')
# Format X-axis ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FixedFormatter(plot_df.index.strftime('%d-%m'))
)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 40})
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(50,50)
plt.show()]
```

This is how it looks:
[With frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJF7g.png)

And how I want it to look:
[With amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilyKL.png)

And this is how my dataset looks like:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovD5V.png)

I have sorted some of the many 20+ columns out for simplicity as well...

Udstedelsesdato is invoice date

Beløb is invoice amount

OrganisationNiveau3 is departments

and the data:

```
    date    Organisation    amount  ID
21-01-2019  a   80,00    1
24-11-2019  b   4.000,00    2
24-03-2019  c   2.250,00    3
21-01-2019  d   3.000,00    4
21-04-2019  e   298,00  5
24-12-2019  a   564,38  6
24-05-2019  b   157,50  7
24-06-2019  c   157,50  8
24-07-2019  d   48,00   9
24-08-2019  e   280,00  10
24-09-2019  a   199,00  11
28-10-2019  b   75,20   12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of the invoices, then instead of size put the sum():

```
plot_df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Udstedelsesdato',freq='M'), 'OrganisationNiveau3'])
        **.sum()**
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .pivot(index='Udstedelsesdato', columns='OrganisationNiveau3', values='sum')
```

If you use .size() when your are grouping you will basically get the counts of the grouped elements. That is why when you would like to get the sum, you need to add the sum of the elements.

Comment: Im not able to keep the .reset and .pivot function for that, right? Won't I loose the some of the restriction?

Comment: And wont I have to say what sum it has to take?

Comment: It wont change anything. Just try it.

Comment: Tried pasting yours into the code and changing mine out ( and ofc removed the **)
But im just getting a "TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'"

Comment: Could you please upload your data (with dummy figures)? Thanks

Comment: Give me a sec, just had dinner

Comment: Done, not the prettiest and only a part of it all, but this is the columns that I use